# Angular UI-Router and nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I´m trying to get my nested states to work, but I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

[Here is my simple example on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GkVitgluY9X2hEIesiCv?p=preview)

Body:

```
<div class="site_container" ui-view></div>
```

There I want to show my site-container, which should always been shown:

```
<header class="main_header">
    <h1>My header</h1>
</header>

<main  ui-view></main>
```

In the -tag I want to switch between some sub-states, for a simple example I only want to show a :

```
<h2>My content</h2>
```

So as result, I want to have:

```
<div class="site_container" ui-view>
    <header class="main_header">
        <h1>My header</h1>
    </header>

    <main  ui-view>
        <h2>My content</h2>
    </main>
</div>
```

Here is my config:

```
angular.module('myApp').config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function (
    $stateProvider,
    $urlRouterProvider
    ) {

    $stateProvider

    .state('main', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    .state('main.child', {
        url: '/child',
        templateUrl: 'child.html',
    })

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/child');
}]);
```

Could you tell me, what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: It might be because you want to use HTML5 routes, in which case you need to add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: Thank you, but this crashes all my relative paths :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `abstract` state has `/` in the URL that means while you are creating a child state, It can have URL with `/child` will be considered as `//child`

Per your current code it should be `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('//child');`

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fU1GyoxHnNlV4Cj9m50e?p=preview)

But technically for making URL user friendly you should declare abstract state with blank (`''`) URL

```
.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '', //<--changed to blank URL
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
```

Then you could make your code working as you posted in question

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5E2kj00xPV3r2Go46Uk?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I removed the "/" before "child". Now it works.

Comment: @Martin Yes I did updated mine answer..with that solution though..And its best solution to do this thing..